# Book recommendation on the Nazis for a (very) advanced reader

Tags: world-war-two, 20th-century, nazi-germany, nazism, great-depression

I want to get my history teacher - who has taught me for three years and given a lot of extra help and support - a book. He has been studying the Nazis for several decades and is very knowledgeable, which makes it difficult for me to know what is a suitable level and would be interesting. If anyone has a recommendation that would be fantastic!

Thank you!

Comment: How will you know he hasn't read what you plan to gift him? :)

Comment: Apart from that, this question is a bit too broad. Perhaps you could find relevant info on Goodreads groups. Maybe here..?  https://www.goodreads.com/group/show/8115-the-history-book-club

Comment: You could offer to [hire them a researcher at the National Archives](https://www.archives.gov/research/hire-help).

Comment: If he's already spent decades on Nazis, perhaps introduce him to a new subject would be more effective?

Comment: I know some people here dont really like Shirer, saying he is more of a journalist than a historian, but "The Rise and Fall of the Third Reich" is a damn comprehensive book if he has never read it before.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a reference request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very hard to recommend a book for an experienced scholar in his own field, because he's likely to have already read it. I have one suggestion, because it's quite obscure.

***I Was A Stranger*** by John Hackett was published in 1977, and reprinted in a limited edition by Slightly Foxed Ltd more recently. It is the story of how an Australian-born British Army officer, seriously wounded and captured at Arnhem, escaped while still wounded and was sheltered by a Dutch family while he recovered, at great risk to themselves. It's a fine illustration of how ordinary people refused to yield to the Nazis. Even if he has already read it, I do not think he will be disappointed by the gift.